# Assign DNN Friendly URL to only one portal on a site that has many portals

Tags: dotnetnuke, friendly-url

I installed DNNFriendlyUrl to my main host site that has several portals in the web config file.

```
<friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
    <providers>
       <clear />
       <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="advanced" /> 
      </providers>
    </friendlyUrl>
```

On the host settings I have edited the extension for Advanced URL Management as Checked for Is Premium Module? Also, I added several portals to Unassigned and only one to assigned. For my several portals that are unassigned by I go into their extensions page the Advance URL management doesn't show. But If I go to the admin page it shows the Advance URL management and the URLs are rewritten for those portal sites.

Is there any way to install the Advanced URL Management to only one portal (of a site that has many portals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly when you switch providers it is for the entire installation.

Comment: Oh, I thought with Premium Module I could assign the extension to only certain portals and disable it for others...

Comment: You can assign the extension. But the actual usage of the rewriter is all portals.